# How to show PHP notices in HTML element attributes with Firefox by default?

Tags: php, html, firefox

My website is realized with PHP. It prints some notices but they appear in HTML element attributes. I use Smarty Templates for my website and refer to variables in element attributes:

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="peter" id="peter" type="text" data-array-values="{$blaa->test|json_encode|escape}" placeholder="Peter" data-validators='["prefixedNotInArray","matchPattern"]' required data-pattern="[0-9A-Z]{'{'}2,8{'}'}" data-abide-validator="multipleValidate" value="{$peter->id|escape}" />
```

The object $blaa does not exist. Therefore it leads to a notice:

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="peter" id="peter" type="text" data-array-values="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: blaa in <b>/var/www/myprogram/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(165) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>217</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/var/www/myprogram/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(165) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>217</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>/var/www/myprogram/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(165) : eval()'d code</b> on line <b>217</b><br />
null" placeholder="Peter" data-validators='["prefixedNotInArray","matchPattern"]' required data-pattern="[0-9A-Z]{2,8}" data-abide-validator="multipleValidate" value="My ID" />
```

The whole element is part of a fieldset of a form element, surrounded by multiple div elements.

Firefox 53.0.2 does not show them automatically. I did only find them by looking at the raw HTML website with Ctrl+U.

Do I have to use the developer tools or some addon to parse the website for notices?

Comment: this is a normal behavior, firefox render your HTML input, and while you are are storing your interrupted object within an attribute that the browser does not render `data-array-values` in the view, so you will not see errors in the screen, rather `to test-mental only` store your object in `value` attribute, you will find it out;

Comment: You could have your error log open and see all errors and notices as they occur.

Comment: Well, the object should not be the value and my question is how I can easily debug a website with the Firefox, so it recognizes such notices.

Comment: I added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hassan mentionned in the comments, this is normal behavior, the message is being outputted correctly, it just isn't showing up as `data-array-values` isn't rendered in the normal browser view. It's an HTML attribute, which is why you only see it when you explore the source code.

If you tried putting `{$blaa->test|json_encode|escape}` in the middle of a `<p>` tag in your page for example, you should see the notice rendered in your browser window.

In doubt, consult your php error log after rendering your page, or try printing out variables in a visible HTML portion of your page beforehand.

Comment: Well, I will check "/var/log/apache2/error.log" then but it would have been much easier if there was some visual tool for this, integrated in the Firefox which could be used with some simple option.

Comment: I understand the problem, but to my knowledge, there are no developper tools that can intercept these strings in the page. Since they can be rendered in various ways (for example, formatting is radically different with x-debug). HTML output helps debugging, but the error log will keep track of everything, including what may or may not be outputted in the browser window